# Running a function if selected input & pressed enter key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a simple function to run when pressing the enter key when the input box is selected. I think it might be a simple fix but cannot find the solution. I assume the problem is runOnEnter("keypress") but I dont know how to pass a 'key' into the argument to be tested by the function.

Can someone tell me how to pass a key into the argument? Or is there another way to fix the problem? thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("this-checker").addEventListener("keypress", runOnEnter("keypress"));

function runOnEnter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         alert('hi');
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="first-div">

          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter url here..." id="this-checker" value="urlhere">
          
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the event like so:

```
.addEventListener("keypress", runOnEnter);
```

And then `e` is passed automatically to `runOnEnter` when the event is triggered.

One additional note, I recommend using [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of `e.keyCode`:

```
function runOnEnter(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
         alert('hi');
    }
}
```

This is to ensure your code works properly across all browsers.

Comment: I tried it with your suggestion but it did not work. Any ideas why? here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x55fan97/

Comment: @user8758206 Sorry I wasn't more clear. You need to call `addEventListener` on your element, as you did in your example. The whole line will be: `document.getElementById("this-checker").addEventListener("keypress", runOnEnter);`

Comment: @user8758206 Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) once the waiting period is over, and best of luck.